# Implement AWS authentication to use end user's resources in Python & Django App

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, authentication

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) and Django(1.10) in which i need to use end user's account resource to make his code deployed on his aws account.

I have set up 2 accounts(1 as my app & 2nd as a user's account) and make authentication successful.But when I have passed this auth in another view it throws some errors.

Here's what I have tried:

From **views.py**:

```
def boto3_with_role(role_arn, session_prefix, external_id, **kwargs):
"""
Create a partially applied session to assume a role with an external id.
A unique session_name will be generated by {session_prefix}_{time}
`session` can be passed, otherwise the default sesion will be used
see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html
"""
sts = boto3.client('sts')
res = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName='{}_{}'.format(session_prefix, int(time.time())),
    ExternalId=external_id,
    *kwargs,
)
creds = res['Credentials']
print(creds)
return partial(boto3.session.Session,
               aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
               aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
               aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken'],
               )


class AwsAuthentication(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        AwsSession =   boto3_with_role('arn:aws:iam::497736713165:role/IstiocloudCrossAccount', 'MyPrefix',
                                 'abd37214@cloud')
        my_session = AwsSession()
        client = my_session.resource('s3')
        for bucket in client.buckets.all():
            print(bucket.name)
            return render(request, 'dockerDep/aws/selectDeployment.html', {'bucket': bucket.name})
        # return HttpResponse('Your Bucket is: {}'.format(bucket.name))

# From here AWS Deployments starting

class AwSlsDeployment(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        AwsSession = boto3_with_role('arn:aws:iam::497736713165:role/IstiocloudCrossAccount', 'MyPrefix',
                                 'abd37214@cloud')
        user_session = AwsSession()
        client = user_session.resource('s3')
        for bucket in client.buckets.all():
            print(bucket.name)
            return render(request, 'dockerDep/aws/slsDeployment.html', {'bucket': bucket.name})
```

When i try to access **AwSlsDeployment** view then it through:

> AwsAuthentication is missing a QuerySet. Define AwsAuthentication.model, AwsAuthentication.queryset, or override AwsAuthentication.get_queryset().

How can I use this authentication from **boto3_with_rol()** to other views?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!